# Typo3 How can i execute my sql query with having clause

Tags: mysql, typo3

This is my SQL query

```
select uid,starttime,endtime
from table1
where endtime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
Group by uid
having min(starttime)
```

When I execute the query with phpmyadmin it return me 2 rows. But when I execute with Typo3, the query return 27000 rows.

```
$select = "uid,starttime,endtime";
$from ="table1";
$where = "endtime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()";
$groupby = "uid having min(starttime)";

$res = $GLOBALS["TYPO3_DB"] -> exec_SELECTquery($select,$from,$where,$groupby);

$sql = $GLOBALS["TYPO3_DB"] -> SELECTquery($select,$from,$where,$groupby);

echo $sql;
echo mysql_num_rows($res);
```

If I remove the having clause in typo3. The query return 2 row but not the good one.

How can I execute this query with the having clause?

Thank for your help

Comment: I don't think the HAVING clause does what you think it does.

Comment: `HAVING` is not a part of the `GROUP BY` clause, it's a separate clause of its own. I suspect Typo3 is ignoring the invalid `$groupby` value you're giving it.

Comment: Try `"uid having starttime = min(starttime)"` instead

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee That's not the correct way to select the row with the minimum starttime for each uid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `exec_SELECTquery()` doesn't support `HAVING` clauses, so you need to use write the query out in full.

If you're trying to get the row for each user that has their minimum start time, the correct query is:

```
SELECT uid,starttime,endtime
from table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT uid, min(starttime) minstart
      FROM table1
      where endtime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
      GROUP BY uid) t2
ON t1.uid = t2.uid AND t1.starttime = t2.starttime
```

Comment: -1. You should not use the native function for that. See maholtz's answer.

Comment: @cascaval My point was that you have to write the query out in full. I didn't know that Typo3 has its own function to perform normal SQL queries. Based on maholtz's answer, it doesn't seem like Typo3 encourages use of that function, or they'd give it a more "normal" name.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Your answer gave me impression that you are familar with TYPO3. Now the answer looks better. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB'] -> sql_query()](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/45/html/classt3lib___d_b.html#a813ec7ab30efb95ec607f14b0c9d74bc) which is an API function. You should avoid nativ mysql-functions. If you use nativ mysql-functions, you will get into trouble without warning when updating to TYPO3 6.2. If you use API-functions you will get a Info if it is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

As the documentation says, the HAVING keyword is followed by a where condition. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) This means that MySQL is interpreting your "min(starttime)" expression as a where condition, and evaluating it to 1 (true) for all non-zero positive values of min(starttime).

For example, "HAVING count(*) > 10" or "HAVING min(starttime) < now()" or whatever are more interesting where conditions.

So, put the condition you want after the HAVING and you'll get whatever you are looking for.

Just to be clear, for anybody who is confused, here's a complete example:

```
select uid,starttime,endtime
from table1
where endtime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
Group by uid
having min(starttime) > datediff(now(), interval 1 week);
```

In this example, "min(starttime) > datediff(now(), interval 1 week)" is the where condition that follows the HAVING keyword.

Comment: Te documentation clearly says that `HAVING` comes after `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yes, @Barmar, that is correct. Why are you pointing that out?

Comment: Because it means you can't put the `HAVING` clause inside `$where`, because that will put it in the wrong place in the query.

Comment: Hey, does whoever downvoted this answer want to say what their problem with the answer is? That would be polite, and allow me to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: @Barmar, I didn't say to put it in $where. A where condition follows the HAVING keyword.

Comment: But where do you put the HAVING clause in the call to `exec_SELECTquery()`?

Comment: `min(starttime)` is a valid where condition, it's short for `min(starttime) != 0`; it's probably not what he wanted, but I suspect that comparing it to a week ago isn't, either.